# Is there maintened plugin doing same thing than 'offline.js'?

Tags: javascript, offline.js

I'm looking for a way to check real time network connection in a webApp.
"Offline.js" do exaclty what I want but there is to much possibilites than only check connection and is not maintened.

Do you know another plugin/code doing exactly the same thing ?

(I also try with "navigator.onLine" but I really need a safe, light and cross-browser solution).

Comment: You can refer to this :
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/workingoffthegrid/#toc-xml-http-request

Comment: Wow, very interesting article, Thank you !